is my prayer valid in this situation?
Recently, I started feeling as though I missed one sujood in my prayers at least once a day. I thought this was from Shaytan, so I ignored the thought whenever it came up during Salah. I have a long history of waswas (whispers) about the number of sujoods I perform, so I assumed that maybe Shaytan was trying to exploit my weakness. Every time the thought came to mind, I pushed it aside.
Today, while praying the third rak'ah, I had doubts about whether or not I performed two sujoods during the sujood. However, I had a gut feeling that I had made two sujoods, and I thought it was just waswas. So, I ignored the doubt. But after I stood up, I started rethinking whether I had made two sujoods or not. Still, I had that gut feeling that I did indeed perform two sujoods, so I ignored the doubt and completed the prayer. However, after finishing, I started to feel as if I might have actually made only one sujood.
Is what I did correct, and is my prayer valid?

Try to make your question more generalised and not personal. This will increase the likelihood of getting answers and would definitely help a larger demographic.
